# Docker run does not exit

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I have the Docker image.

Docker file is here:

```
FROM debian:stable
CMD ["sleep", "300"]
```

Then I do:

Window #1:

```
docker build .
```

...and...

Window #1:

```
docker run xx
```

Window #2:

```
docker exec xx ps
```

Result:

```
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 ?        00:00:00 sleep
      6 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

Docker works, but I cann't break it.

I try many combination (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-A, Ctrl-D, Ctrl-P, Ctrl-Q, exit...) but it does not work. It shows a blank line till end of time.

Docker is installed on Ubuntu 20.04.
I work on Ubuntu 22.04 over SSH with Tilix.
May be signal was lost along the way.

p.s. I saw video on YouTube with command `docker run --rm --name mydocker myimagex:v01` - Author had black line after this command either, but it worked for him with Ctrl-C. But I do not think `remove` and `name` affect on this behavior. I'm confused.

Comment: INT signal is sent to the container and handled by process with PID 1 which is treated specially by kernel and isn't killed an since you don't have a proper init in place it doesn't kill all of its children, see https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/01/dumb-init-an-init-for-docker.html#process-behavior-inside-docker-containers

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Why I don't have a proper init I follow recommendation Docker's site I use `CMD ["sleep", "300"]` and I have `sleep` with `PID 1`. Or I misunderstand something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux kernel treats PID 1 in a special way and apply different rules in relation to how to handle signals and it doesn't get the default signal handlers. This means that it does not kill the process when receiving the SIGNALS, e.g. `SIGTERM`, `SIGSTOP`, `SIGINT`.

To kill the process:

- from outside the container, use `SIGKILL`: `kill -s 9 <pid>`
- from inside the container, specify [--init](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process) when you execute it with the `docker run --init` for proper process management and signal handling.

The `–-rm` flag is used to say to the Docker daemon to clean and remove the container, and volumes after the container exits to save disk space. So it's not related to the SIGNAL handling. Neither is the `--name` option.

Comment: ok, I see, thanks a lot. But one question. Do I have this case only? I mean as I said I saw video at YT, author typed command without `--init` and `Ctrl-C` worked for him. Or maybe he setup `--init` by default, but how. Is there guess why it works for him?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. Just to name a few ways to handle signal "normally": 1) install dumb-init (https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init) inside your container, 2) install tini (https://github.com/krallin/tini) from the Dockerfile; 3) use DIY Signal Handler, a program capable of listening and generating signals, by installing custom signal handlers for SIGNALS directly in your application code so, when you run docker exec, it will replace the running process with your application.

Comment: @Pro did my replies solved your doubts? If yes, please, upvote/accept the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I always accept question whet the last is fully solved.
I understood, In video review `nginx` with `Dockerfile`. Apparently `nginx` can correctly work with signals itself as you said, that's why `Ctrl-C` works for author. It work for me too when I exactly repeated his example. It's very useful answer for me.